# Magento remove customer review block from product view page

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, review

I am creating custom module for customer review so I need to delete the Magento customer review functionality from product view page. There is any XML code which don't show the Magento customer review on product view page.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have just tried the xml code <remove name="customer.review"/>

Comment: I want to delete it by custom module from xml code. Any way to delete the magento customer review from magento

Comment: please show the review xml code and custom module layout xml code

Comment: <catalog_product_view>
    <remove name="customer_review"/>
 <reference name="product.info">
  <block type="testimonial/monblock" name="testimonial.block" as="additional" template="testimonial/viewMore.phtml">
     <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
     <action method="setTitle" translate="value">  <value>Review</value></action>
             </block>
 </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>

Answer (score 0):

try this code i have already used...

```
<catalog_product_view ranslate="label">
     <remove name="product.reviews"/>
 </catalog_product_view>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your theme folder> template> catalog> product> open view.phtml then just find  the code in this page:`<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'default', false)?>`
Now remove the code and check. I think it solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any xml code to remove customer review block from product view page. Go to System > Configuration > Advanced then look for Mage_Review and disable it.